Children trapped in a house
I recall a film where children (maybe brother/sister) were stuck in their country home. Unable to get out because small creatures would get them. To protect themselves they made a circle around the house.
The story might have started out with the young boy knowing there are creatures (maybe in the walls), but no one believes him. It could be that they just moved into the this house.
There might have been a magical book involved as well.
The film must have come out in the last 10 years or so.

@Paulie_D how could I possibly post a duplicate question 3 years before the other was posted?

They are duplicates and the timing isn't really relevant. We just use what seems to be the most detailed question as the "main" question and use the duplicates as pointers.

I believe this is The Spiderwick Chronicles (2007)
It contains all the elements you describe.  A family move into at a country house.  One of the children starts to see things before the others, starting in the walls of the house and eventually meets the resident Brownie who is tasked with keeping the house safe. In keeping with some cliches - he is the child most disturbed by the separation of his parents, and the other family members do not believe his stories at first.
They find that the house is under attack by (small) Goblins who are kept out by a magic circle.  The goblins are working for a 'big bad' (a troll I think) who is after the 'Field Guide' of Arthur Spiderwick, an ancestor of the family.  The field guide documents all the magical creatures, and will make the 'big bad' all powerful.
